# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Platform'

Tags: python

I have looked through similar questions but it didn't seem to help me to answer my question. I'm making a game with pygame and I am getting this error with one class. The aim of this code is to return a list of platforms in a group called 'level', that are touching the instance of platform :

```
        block = platform.Platform(platform[0])
```

and this line keeps returning this error:

```
block = platform.Platform(platform[0])
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Platform'

Code for platform:

```py
class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
 
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        
        global sprite_sheet
        
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(FOREST)
 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
 
        #sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("spritesheet.png")
        # Grab the image for this platform
        #self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(sprite_sheet_data[0],
                                            #sprite_sheet_data[1],
                                            #sprite_sheet_data[2],
                                            #sprite_sheet_data[3])
 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Some of the main code:

```py
def main():
    """ Main Program """
    pygame.init()
 
    # Set the height and width of the screen
    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
 
    pygame.display.set_caption("Totoro's Adventure")
 
    # Create the player
    player = Player()
 
    # Create all the levels
    level_list = []
    level_list.append(levels.Level_01(player))
    level_list.append(levels.Level_02(player))
 
    # Set the current level
    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
 
    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level
 
    player.rect.x = 340
    player.rect.y = constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
    active_sprite_list.add(player)
 
    #Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False
```

Code for Level_01:

```py
class Level_01(Level):
 
    def __init__(self, player):
 
        # Call the parent constructor
        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.background = pygame.image.load("set/Main_bg.png").convert()
        self.background.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.level_limit = -2500

        level = [400, 640, -700, 0, #wall
                 450, 40, -300, 0, #plat l
                 190, 40, 150, 120, #plat s
                 190, 40, 300, 00, #plat m
                 190, 40, 450, 280, #plat s
                 210, 40, 800, 180, #plat m
                 500, 40, 800, 500, #plat l
                 210, 40, 1500, 340, #plat 
                 40, 350, 800, 180, #wall
                 210, 40, 1500, 180, #plat
                 70, 470, 1500, 180, #wall 2
                 ]

        # Go through the array above and add platforms
        for platform in level:
            block = platforms.Platform(platform[0])
            block.rect.x = platform[1]
            block.rect.y = platform[2]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)
```

Comment: You're trying to access the class `Platform` from the import `platforms`. However, python reports that `platforms` is a list. So maybe somewhere in your code you've overridden the variable `platforms` with a list as a value? Never name your variables the same as your imports, because you'll override them.

Comment: The line which is throwing you an error should be `platforms. Platform(platform[0])`. In the code part it seems to be correctly written, but at the top, where you show the error, it seems like a syntax issue. I would suggest changing the name of the custom list to avoid such confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the elements of the list platform with their indices and pass them as arguments to the Platform constructor:

```
for platform in level:
    block = platforms.Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
    block.rect.x = platform[2]
    block.rect.y = platform[3]
    block.player = self.player
    self.platform_list.add(block)
```